# Saving the Firebase storage.getDownloadURL() to Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

Please give me a hand in saving the https:// URL to my firebase database under specific user. Here is the code snippet:

```
if(filePath != null)
    {
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        String userUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        /*to be deleted - tests to save the profile image under wardrobe child*/
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(userUid).child("WARDROBE");
        //end of tobedeleted

        //StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference(userUid).child("images/" + filePath.getLastPathSegment());
        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference(userUid).child("images/" + "profilePicture");
        UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(filePath);
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                databaseReference.push().setValue(taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString());//to be deleted
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(CropProfilePicture.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(CropProfilePicture.this, Profile.class));
            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(CropProfilePicture.this, "Failed "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        //double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
                    }
                });
```

The saved URL is not the https:// URL but this:

```
"com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@367c82"
```

Comment: @Doug Stevenson thank you for pointing that to me. Been searching the whole time.